# 502 Bad Gateway after multiple request on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, bad-gateway

When working from the Office and multiple developers are hitting the server we start to randomly receive 502 error bad gateway. (Around one out of 10 hits)

We are using Compute Engine with a Load Balancer HTTPs.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons that the Load Balancer would return a 502 error. Have a look at the [logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?minLogLevel=0&expandAll=false&interval=NO_LIMIT&resource=http_load_balancer&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22http_load_balancer%22%0AhttpRequest.status%3D502) (this is a custom link to retrieve load balancer 502 errors specifically; just pick your project at the top) -- specifically at the `jsonPayload.statusDetails` field of the errors in question -- then correlate the `statusDetails` value against the [reason](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#statusdetail_http_failure_messages).